# Incompatible block pointer types using typedef

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

For a day now I've been trying to get a piece of code working to help me handle find-and-create for CoreData in a nice way (from this article I found http://emplementation.blogspot.nl/2011/12/importing-data-into-core-data-while.html). I ended up working with code blocks which I've never done before.

Somehow I can't fix the following error which occurs because something is different in my typedef from what I try to define in my function. I think I understand it has something to do with the block being defined as __strong in the typedef but differently in my implementation file.

Error

> Incompatible block pointer types initializing '_*strong objectOperationBlock' (aka 'void (^*_strong)(NSManagedObjectContext *_*strong, NSDictionary **_strong, NSManagedObject *_*strong)') with an expression of type 'void (^)(NSManagedObject **_strong, NSDictionary *_*strong, NSManagedObject **_strong)'

MyViewController.h

```
typedef void (^objectOperationBlock)(NSManagedObjectContext *context,
                                 NSDictionary *hostObjectData,
                                 NSManagedObject *localManagedObject);
```

MyViewController.m

```
objectOperationBlock matchedBlock = ^(NSManagedObject *context, NSDictionary *hostObjectData, NSManagedObject *localManagedObject){
    NSLog(@"Dosomething");
};
```

In all my attempts I've found out that this could will build (but it's not using the typedef)

```
void (^matchedBlock)(NSManagedObject*, NSDictionary*, NSManagedObject*) = ^(NSManagedObject *context, NSDictionary *hostObjectData, NSManagedObject *localManagedObject){
    NSLog(@"Dosomething");
};
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Cannot repeat this issue. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did I miss that the typedef should read:

```
typedef void (^objectOperationBlock)(NSManagedObject *managedObject,
                                     NSDictionary *hostObjectData,
                                     NSManagedObject *localManagedObject);
```

Comment: Or, conversely, that the `context` variable in the assignment should be `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: You are very right, no wonder it didn't work..

Thanks a lot, I need to get myself some fresh air!

Comment: Easy miss - I've been staring at 10 year old Makefiles all morning (don't ask!), just spotted omission.